# exluding part of html based on xPath

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I am trying to scrappe for this [page](http://www.toysrus.com/product/index.jsp?productId=3685677&cp=2255956.2273442.2469772.3263938&green)

[image]

I am using xPath to select this, my code is ..

```
$safeFlag = true ;
//*[@id="tabset_productPage"]/dd[1]/div/div   //HAVE TRIED THIS TOO
//*[@id="tabset_productPage"]/dd[1]/div/div  // HAVE TRIED THIS
$safety_query='//*[@id="tabset_productPage"]/dd[1]/div/div/text()'; 
    $safety = $xpath->query($description_query);



    foreach ($safety as $word1) {

        $safety_warning[]=(trim($word1->nodeValue));
        if($safety_warning != ''){
        $safeFlag = false ;
        $safety_warning[]= 'NO SAFETY WARNING..';
        }
    }


var_dump($safety_warning);
```

and for description text, I use xPath like

```
//*[@id="tabset_productPage"]/dd[1]
```

but issue is, using all of this, I get both safetywarning and description completely..

My issue is, I want to select SAFETY WARNING and DESCRIPTION texts separately, but I always get them as a whole, complete text including safety warning and description ,for all of the xPath above.. 
Also, html structure is not always same..description at some time can have `<br> or <p>` tags placed so,

can somebody guide me? some suggestion or out line how can I achieve this? how can put safety warning / description in saparate columns / variables while both are child of same element..

thanks..

Comment: @N e w B e e Tricky question. Still searching for a xpath solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safety warning is the first text child node of `//dl[@id="tabset_productPage"]/dd[1]/`. To exclude it from selection you can select all text nodes with a position greater than 1. The query to obtain the description would look like:

```
$description_query='//dl[@id="tabset_productPage"]/dd[1]/text()[position()>1]';
```

I've prepared an example to test it. Here it comes:

```
$link = 'http://www.toysrus.com/product/index.jsp?productId=3685677&cp=2255956.2273442.2469772.3263938&green';

$html = file_get_contents($link);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHtml($html);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$safety_query='//*[@id="tabset_productPage"]/dd[1]/div/div/text()';
$safety = $selector->query($safety_query);
$safety_warning = $safety->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo 'Safety Warning: ', $safety_warning, PHP_EOL;

// select text nodes with a position greater than 1
$description_query='//dl[@id="tabset_productPage"]/dd[1]/text()[position()>1]';
$description_result = $selector->query($description_query);

$paragraphs = array();
foreach($description_result as $node) {
    $value = $node->nodeValue;
    if(trim($value) !== '') {
        $paragraphs []= $value;
    }   
}

$description = implode(PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, $paragraphs);
echo 'Description: ', $description, PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: i think it was $html = file_get_contents($link); here at my end, I used it with my own scrapping class and it works like a charm...thanks...thanks for you help

Comment: just one more thing, as If safety warning is not there, it will still go for position, and might miss something, right?

Comment: Yes, I assumed it will be always there. It is of course a very fragile solution (but you asked for ;) ).. If you ask me I would select first the safety warning. Then I would select the whole text content including the safety warning and the description. Then I would replace the safety warning using `str_replace()` from the description. That sounds more reliable to me. Also you can remove the <div class="securityWaringDiv"> if present (using DOM manipulation). (after getting the warning text)

Comment: I was actually doing it in my code $src = str_replace($find, $replace, $src); but it was failing in replacing the safety warning,and to cater page structure change, I will use  $safeFlag . also, I really like if(trim($value) !== '') , thats really cool. cursing myself why it did not came in my mind

Comment: Ok, I wish you a happy scraping :)

Comment: Call to undefined method DOMText::item() in ....getting this error now , any clues?

Comment: nay, trying to debug it, I think at that page, safety warning would not be there, so got this error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23174/discussion-between-n-e-w-b-e-e-and-hek2mgl)

Comment: Try to follow my comment above. Will save you head aches

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
//div[@class = "safetyWarning"]
```

for the safety warning and

```
//div[@id= "infoPanel"]/dl/dd/text()
```

for the product description?

Comment: My mistake. Added a path for the description.